# Why cannot I override the context for bpy.ops.object.origin_set()

Tags: python, selection-tools, origin

I ran the following code to reset the origin of Cube:

```
import bpy
# set selection
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].select = False
bpy.data.objects["Plane"].select = True

# override context
override = bpy.context.copy()
override["selected_bases"] = [bpy.data.scenes[0].object_bases["Cube"]]
override["active_base"] = bpy.data.scenes[0].object_bases["Cube"]

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(override)  # works on Plane
bpy.ops.transform.translate(override, value=(1,1,1))  # works on Cube
```

However this resets the origin of the Plane instead. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @batFINGER I reported it to the bug tracker just in case it is really a bug. https://developer.blender.org/T57572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the blender bug tracker https://developer.blender.org/T57572

> operator `origin_set` relies on `selected_editable_objects` afaict, so adding `override["selected_editable_objects"] = [bpy.data.objects["Cube"]]` should do the trick:

Comment: Good to know. Thought wait a minute I tried that one unsuccessfully before commenting, on further investigation `"selected_editalbe_objects"`